# chunks from javascript to bytes or stream with flask API

Tags: flask, stream, speech-to-text, getusermedia, bytestream

I am sending chunks of audio data from javascript browser using getUsermedia to flask python api for speech to text. Initially I used to convert audio chunks to blob and then used file approach for speech text. Now i would like to use stream instead of file/blob. Can any one help on flask logic to convert audio chunks to stream or bytes. I am getting "Cannot convert list to bytes" error in flask api when i am trying to send chunks like below enter code here

```
Smaple loigc
chunks=[]
in ondataavilable(){
chunks.push(e.data)
}
```